# Why is one 'for of' working while a similar isn't?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm iterating over an array translating strings in angular, but only the 'map' option works, the 'for' doesn't.

```
chart.categories = chart.categories.map(function (category) 
    return $translate.instant(category);
});
```

> NOT WORKING
>
> ```
> for (categorie of chart.categories) {
>     categorie = $translate.instant(categorie);
> }
> ```

On the other hand when I iterate over chart.series like this, it works:

```
for (serie of chart.series) {
    serie.name = $translate.instant(serie.name);
}
```

Does it have anything to to with the fact that in the second for I'm translating a property while in the first for i'm translating the object itself?

Edit:

Here's my chart object:

```
{
  "categories": [
    "JOSÉ HERLANI DA CRUZ",
    "Class"
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Attendance Percentage in Class",
      "data": [
        100,
        100
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The codes don't seem to be doing the same thing. The first chunk doesn't use `name`, whereas the second does.

Comment: yes, i realize that, the first one category is a string while the second one serie is an object with the 'name' property being a string, but shouldn't they work the same?

Comment: No, since in the first chunk, the for loop is reassigning the local reference which doesn't do anything. `categorie = $translate` just changes what the local `catagorie` is.

Comment: but why doesn't serie.name = $translate just changes what the local serie.name is too? It changes in the original object too

Comment: May we see what `chart.categories` and `chart.series` actually contain?

Comment: @StudioWorks `series.name =` works because you're altering the object itself, whereas the other loop doesn't alter the object, only a reference to the object.

Comment: @SebastianGaweda I edited my original post. 'Attendance percentage in class" gets translated, but "Class" doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `(for item of items)` you can't change the `item`, as item is a new local variable and only that on you're changing. Not the on in `items`.  You could change `item.property` as the reference `item` is still in `items`

e.g. if you have this:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = a;
b = 2;

console.log("a =", a);
console.log("b =", b);
```

`b` will be `2` and `a` will be still `1` (unchanged)

but if you have this:

```js
var a = {}
a.x = 1;
var b = a;
b.x = 2;

console.log("a.x =", a.x);
console.log("b.x =", b.x);
```

both `a.x` and `b.x` are `2`, as they reference the same.

I think that is also what you have concluded with

> Does it have anything to to with the fact that in the second for I'm translating a property while in the first for i'm translating the object itself?

this would work:

```js
var newCategories = [];
for (categorie of chart.categories) {
    newCategories.push($translate.instant(categorie));
}
chart.categories = newCategories
```

Comment: Or just `map` again. This is the intended use case for `map`.

Comment: more than true. Except I like `for of` better as it won't has lambdas and that's good for performance and error messages. But that's maybe a detail

Comment: OK, thanks for the time. It seem when you alter the object reference it doesn't change the original, while altering the property does, but as to why that happens didn't get very clear to me. Why does a.x and b.x reference the same, but b doesn't. doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @StudioWorks When you use `=` you're changing what object is being looked at by the variable. If you just do `a =`, you're changing what object `a` looks at. If that's in a narrow scope like a loop though, the `a` reference will be destroyed when the loop exits, so changing it has no effect. With `a.x =` though you're changing what `x` value the **object that `a` is pointing to** holds. You'll just need to practice thinking about what it means to alter references to objects vs what it means to alter objects. Those are two distinct concepts, and the distinction can be confusing at first.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Right, I got it now, thanks man, you're very helpful.